# noty, call a function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

This is a prototype function I use for displaying confirmation with buttons using [noty](http://ned.im/noty/).

```
function confirmation(message, call_func)
{
    var m=noty(
    {
        text: message,
        modal: true,
        layout : 'center',
        theme: 'notifications',
        buttons: [
        {
            addClass: 'general-button red', text: 'Yes', onClick: function($noty)
            {
                   call_func;
               $noty.close();
            }
        },
        {
            addClass: 'general-button', text: 'No', onClick: function($noty)
            {
                $noty.close();
            }
        }]
    });
    return m;
}
```

I am calling this function with the syntax,

```
confirmation("Are you sure want to delete this item?", "delete("+id+")");
```

So on clicking the Yes button, another function `delete(id)` have to be called. But it does not, why?

I checked with alert, `alert(call_func)`. I alerts as **delete(10)** where 10 is ID at the instance.

Comment: try this eval(call_func); instead of just call_func;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here you are not calling the function

```
call_func;
```

you are just referencing it

And here you are just building a string

```
"delete("+id+")")
```

it is not a reference to a function call.

---

What you need to do is pass in an actual function and execute the function.

```
confirmation("Are you sure want to delete this item?", function(){ delete(id); });
```

and

```
call_func();
```